# AnyLogic pedestrians stalled upon entering scene

Tags: anylogic, traffic-simulation

I've set PedSource for a Node. But fair amount of pedestrians after emerging into the scene don't move. Some of them eventually start moving if other, properly functioning pedestrians bumping into them. But that glitch upsets the entire simulaiton.
Is there a tolerance or anything I can crank-up to see proper simulation?
In the printscreen stalled pedestians highlighted with marker. Printscreen is done at realtime running model for 30 mins.
[image]

Here is print-screen of my logic
[image]

I moved the node a bit. Sometime it helps. But in general I can't find solution for it.

Comment: Pic of the process logic might help :)

Comment: @Benjamin I've added my logic process printscreen. I hope that'll help.

Comment: This is far too complex to comment, could be 100s of things. Strip back your model until the problematic behavior disappears. Then, step by step, add it back until you find the culprit. And in the future, always develop like this: add a TINY feature. Testtesttesttest. If all works 100%, add another TINY feature and repeat. Only that way can you avoid such "traps" of "why does it not work"...